# flutter local notification if i turn off the phone

Tags: flutter, localnotification, flutter-local-notification

I wanted to use this package (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to schedule local notifications on my app.

I know it is possible to show them even if the app is turned off; but if I restart the phone will the notifications that are scheduled then be shown? Or will all the notifications in the queue be deleted?

I give an *example* to be more clear: I schedule a notification in 1 hour -> I immediately turn off and restart the phone -> after 1 hour the notification will be shown?

-

*I hope I have been clear enough. Thank you.*

Comment: why don't you try for yourself? What is the issue here !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found [Awesome Notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) much easier and way less complicated that the package you're using.